# How to achieve full NuGet reinstall for dozens of solutions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

We have dozens of solutions in a repository and we're retargeting every project to `net472` from `net462`. Currently our best bet is to open each and every solution in Visual Studio and execute the following command in the Package Manager Console.

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies
```

As far as I'm aware, the PM console cannot be used outside Visual Studio, so this method of course is not very efficient, so what I was thinking about is using the `nuget.exe` tool for this. However at first glance I could not find any equivalent operation or argument set.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) at this moment says the following

> For all packages, delete the package folder, then run nuget install.
> For a single package, delete the package folder and use nuget install
>  to reinstall the same one.

So based on this I tried to delete the `packages` folder and run `nuget install` for a project, so I expected it to do a re-install. However, while it installed the package indeed (to `packages`), it does not touch the `packages.config` (for retargeting).

Is anyone aware of any kind of possible way to automate this process?

Comment: Yes, it's not very efficient and doesn't get any better. Which is why you should move to .NET Standard for class libraries and .NET Core in general, as soon as possible. You should probably target 4.8 too, not just 4.7.2. 4.8 has been out long enough and the next migration will be to .NET Core 5 anyway. Why have to deal with the bugs in 4.7.2 that were already fixed in 4.8?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I do agree, but of course unfortunately that's not an option for now :)

Comment: .NET Standard *is* an option, especially if you target 4.7.2 and later. You *no longer need to handle all transient dependencies*. Your current problem essentially disappears. You only need to handle a few top-level dependencies and get rid of quite a bit of the compatibility hell you're going through right now

Comment: Been there by the way. Wrote the Powershell scripts to try and update all projects in a solution, tried to fix the compatibility hell caused by 4.6.2's *non*compliance with .NET Standard 2.0. Guess what - what runs on your machine may still *fail* in production. In the end it was even easier to just change to the new `csproj` format by hand than handle the upgrades like this.

Comment: A big part of the upgrade pain now is caused by the old csproj and packages.config, and having to upgrade transient dependencies. If you're able to move to `PackageReference` even in the old format, you save some time. You may be able to [just right-click on a project node and select Migrate to PackageReference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/#:~:text=Migrate%20your%20projects%20to%20PackageReference,config%20to%20PackageReference%E2%80%A6.). This will allow you to keep only the root dependencies. No more `System.Memory` to update

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand your point, it is an option but not for now as I wrote. Migrate 10+ solution, each having about 50 projects is a lot of effort so at first we'd like to avoid it. Of course if there's no way, we will consider upgrading to `PackageReference` with or without the new project format.

Comment: As I said, I tried to avoid that too. Didn't work out. Going to `PackageReference` in the old format will reduce the number of packages that need upgrading dramatically. A *lot* of the packages you have to migrate now are transient dependencies that can be removed once you move to the new format.

Comment: You can write a powershell script that iterates over each project in a solution and runs `Update-Package`. This can fail due to conflicts with the transient dependencies though. Different root packages may depend on different versions of eg `System.Diagnostics` and fail to upgrade due to this. Once you *remove* that package though, the command will work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that `Update-Package` command is available only within PM console, and on the other hand, `nuget.exe` does not seem to have a signature to achieve the same effect as `-Reinstall`.

Comment: It's still a PowerShell console with access to the project file system. You can use [Get-Project -All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-project) to retrieve all projects in the solution. You can loop over the results and pass the project name to `Update-Package` with the `-ProjectName` parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, this is exactly what I'm doing right now, but the pain is that I have to load Visual Studio for each and every solution. Thank you for your comments though.

Comment: You may able to write `Get-Project -All | Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies`. It that works without problems, you're already luckier than I was. You could create a single big solution with all projects and update all of them

Comment: It doesn't work exactly like that, but it's close. This is what I'm currently using
`Get-Project -All | foreach { Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies -ProjectName $_.Name }`

Comment: I think it's time to ping Mads Kristensen.

Answer (score 0):

> How to achieve full NuGet reinstall using nuget.exe CLI?

That command cannot get what you want.

**As far as I know**, `nuget install` should be with `packages.config` file and it will not update the nuget framework version of `packages.config` file automatically.

[image]

So whenever you change the target framework version of your project, using that command will not update the target framework version of the nuget package.

So only `update-package -reinstall` command under **Package Manager Console** will update the target framework version of `packages.config` file.

And also **Package Manager Console** cannot access multiple solutions so you have to open each solution to run that command.

**Although** it may be possible to achieve your expectations with PowerShell scripts, but it is too complex so that it is easier to open each solution and then run the command.

**As a suggestion**,

**1)** open each solution on VS to run `update-package -reinstall` command.

**2**) And [migrating from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) may be a good choice. In this case, the nuget packages will automatically adapt to the corresponding project target framework version.

**Before doing this,you can make a backup of your project.**

**3)** If these all do not meet your requirements, you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) to report your desire for automation. After that, you can share the link here and anyone who is interested in it will vote it so that it will get more attention from **Microsoft**.

Comment: We've already been through all of this in the comments. The OP is already using Powershell to iterate over all projects and reinstall the packages. The question is how to avoid opening a ton of projects just to reinstall through PM. We even discussed the merits of moving to PackageReferences or moving to the new csproj format directly, as the pain of upgrading is actually worse than migrating the project format

Comment: And no, take it from a former Microsoft MVP: User Voice Forum won't get any attention from Microsoft. SO exists precisely because Technet Forums contain a lot of bad answers marked as accepted by the MS employees that posted them, and telling people to go to User Voice Forum instead of providing answers.

Comment: The truth is, anything posted in User Voice is ignored for several years. Attention is paid to the requests of big paying customers, not user requests. The only way to get the attention of a team is to *bypass the marketing/management folks* involved in User Voice and  talk to them directly: post issues on their Github repos or ping them on Twitter.